Add hint to block insert/update for specific value
I have a very classic multi-threading problem on SQL Server to control lock behavior by data value, but I cannot find the correct keyword to search solution.
Assume we have table A with 2 primary key columns GroupID and ItemID on a Read-Committed database
CREATE TABLE A (
    GroupID INT
    , ItemID INT
    , Attribute1 VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY (GroupID, ItemID)
)

How could I efficiently block insert/update/delete for specific GroupID value only, and that value might not be table at the beginning?
Such as all GroupID = 1 transactions need to run one-by-one (ignore sequence) but a new GroupID = 2 transaction can fluently process at the same time.
I know UPDLOCK can perfectly run if GroupID already exist situation, but it fail to handle two new GroupID insert at the time. And other found solutions also have side effect:

Separate GroupID to upper level table, but it is very high cost to modify existing code of my real case and new table still need to use TABLOCK to handle INSERT situation
Use TABLOCK to lock whole table, but has huge performance lost

TRUNCATE TABLE A
DECLARE @GroupID INT = 1 --Change to 2 in other thread
DECLARE @RowCount INT
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(*) FROM A WITH(TABLOCKX) WHERE A.GroupID = @GroupID

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10' --Comment in other thread

INSERT INTO A SELECT @GroupID,@RowCount+1,'Value1'

COMMIT TRAN
--Thread 2 must wait Thread 1 complete


Use HOLDLOCK or SERIALIZABLE to force all transactions run in order, still has huge performance lost

TRUNCATE TABLE A
DECLARE @GroupID INT = 1 --Change to 2 in other thread
DECLARE @RowCount INT
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(*) FROM A WITH(UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) WHERE A.GroupID = @GroupID

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10' --Comment in other thread

INSERT INTO A SELECT @GroupID,@RowCount+1,'Value1'

COMMIT TRAN
--Thread 2 must wait Thread 1 complete

So may I know there is other way to handle this case, or some key word I can use to search? Thank!

(Updated)
After team brainstorming, we have below temporary solution which fit our no delete action circumstance

It can block same GroupID transaction
It allow other GroupID run parallelly

--Use UDPLOCK, HOLDLOCK only if exist delete action
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM A WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE A.GroupID = @GroupID) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM A WITH(UPDLOCK, READPAST) WHERE A.GroupID = @GroupID)
    SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(*) FROM A WITH(UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) WHERE A.GroupID = @GroupID
ELSE
    SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(*) FROM A WITH(UPDLOCK) WHERE A.GroupID = @GroupID

However, I strongly doubt that there have week point of time gap exited between NOLOCK and UPDLOCK.
We still use it just because we normally run 3 times of testing with 4M rows 4 threads, and we able to take risk if only fail monthly.

(Updated#2)
I tested @siggemannen suggestion with sp_getapplock is the best method to solve my case instead of above potential failure method.
But with my testing result as below, it is really base on your action pattern so might not fit for everyone:



Method
New/Exist GroupID ratio
Thread 1
Thread 2
Thread 3
Thread 4




UPDLOCK+HOLDLOCK
100%/0%
36:30
36:31
36:32
36:33


NOLOCK+READPASS
100%/0%
11:09
11:07
13:38
11:09


sp_getapplock
100%/0%
12:26
12:24
12:24
12:21


UPDLOCK+HOLDLOCK
75%/25%
21:20
11:24
11:28
11:38


NOLOCK+READPASS
75%/25%
10:22
10:06
10:05
10:11


sp_getapplock
75%/25%
12:20
12:38
12:41
12:45


UPDLOCK+HOLDLOCK
50%/50%
10:26
10:24
10:25
10:27


NOLOCK+READPASS
50%/50%
13:25
13:24
13:24
13:31


sp_getapplock
50%/50%
13:55
13:49
13:42
14:12


UPDLOCK+HOLDLOCK
25%/75%
11:01
11:01
11:13
11:15


NOLOCK+READPASS
25%/75%
11:29
11:30
12:09
12:08


sp_getapplock
25%/75%
13:22
13:11
13:38
13:58


UPDLOCK+HOLDLOCK
0%/100%
09:36
09:42
09:47
09:47


NOLOCK+READPASS
0%/100%
11:35
11:45
12:13
12:15


sp_getapplock
0%/100%
12:50
13:07
13:32
13:31




It would help if you explained why exactly you think you need to lock the rows manually rather than letting SQL Server do it automatically?

Because SQL Server auto method is like method 2/3, 2nd thread request need to wait 1st thread complete. And I also hard to explain with superiors what did I to to prevent possible deadlock problem......

I don't think you understand deadlocks - they don't happen due to multi-threading and if you require your threads to complete in order, why use multi-threading at all? Just run a single thread

Example is simplified and real case is select data>lot of business logic>update+insert in cursor loop of ItemID under same GroupID and deadlock is happened while multiple trigger points calling same GroupID. Previous solution is add TABLOCKX to block everything but cause the task unable finish on time. So as post said, I need to 1)  block same GroupID, 2) allow different GroupID run parallel

Honestly I think you need to rethink the design. Get rid of the cursor and triggers. Otherwise I think your only solution is the one you are using

Can you store your calculated values in a temp table and then just do one big update against the real table at the end with appropriate locks?

@RR378393 what's the problem you want to solve by using multiple connections called "threads" ? Explain the real problem, don't simplify it. In almost every case where such code is used, it's an attempt to implement queues or message passing without actually using QUEUE

We not use Queue/Service Broker before, but sounds like it processed like single thread? Because we have time limit to complete the task.
And @siggemannen, even change to use temp table to replace middle cursor, I still need a lock on table to stop new transaction with same GroupID, so it return to TABLOCK or HOLDLOCK?

Ok, i think i know what you need, sp_getapplock: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 If you have some magic GroupID that needs serialized, you can place a lock when starting some thread that needs to process this GroupID, it will then block all other processes if they try to process same ID value. But if you have some other Group, you don't need to place the lock, boom

@siggemannen thanks for your suggestion and that should be what I want


I know UPDLOCK can perfectly run if GroupID already exist situation, but it fail to handle two new GroupID insert at the time.

Add HOLDLOCK.  This adds the empty range locking behavior of the SERIALIZABLE isolation level.

to force all transactions run in order, still has huge performance lost

That's not what it does.  It literally just adds range locking.  SERIALIZABLE doesn't actually force transactions to run sequentially.  It allows them to run concurrently, but will cause transactions to fail with a deadlock if they aren't "serializable".
SERIALIZABLE transactions deadlock because SELECT uses and holds shared range locks.  When two transactions acquire shared range locks on the same row, neither can update that row, and if they both try, they will deadlock.
If only one needs to update the row that the other transaction read, it will block until the other transaction commits.  But since the value is unchanged by the other transaction, the resulting state of the database is the same as if the transactions had run sequentially.
But in combination with UPDLOCK you get pessimistic locking that prevents
deadlocks.

I suspect the real problem has nothing to do with the question and would benefit from Service Broker
